# Statistic to compare multiple discrete empirical distributions; no sample counts

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Can you suggest an appropriate analysis method?

Data I’m trying to analyze:

- A bunch of related discrete probability distributions $P_i(x)$. These distributions are empirical but they are not generated from samples. (Instead, they are generated in one shot with a deep neural network.)
- Each distribution $P_i(x)$ is across $N_i$ classes, where in general $N_i \neq N_{i+1}$; the "null hypothesis" that each distribution is the discrete uniform distribution, i.e. $P_i(x_j) = 1/N_i$. (Putting "null hypothesis" in quotes here since it may be an abuse of terminology.)
- I want to compute a statistic independent of the number of classes in each distribution that records how “surprising” a given probability $P_i(x_j)$ is given the null hypothesis. I’d like this statistic to be comparable across distributions $P_i$.

For example, suppose I have two empirical distributions $P_1$ and $P_2$:

```
P_1: {class A: 0.33, class B: 0.67}
P_2: {class C: 0.33, class D: 0.33, class E: 0.34}
```

I don't know anything about these distributions except that I originally expected them to be uniform. Clearly, $P_1$ is less uniform than $P_2$, but how do I quantify that independent of the number of classes in each distribution? The statistics for $P_1$ should be further from their null-case value than for $P_2$.

I don't have a quantitative way of describing how much deviation a 2-class distribution requires to be equivalent to the deviation in a 10-class distribution, and am open to suggestion / best practice.

My objective is not to perform a hypothesis test per se but instead to efficiently find extreme $P_i(x_j)$.

It doesn't seem like the Chi-squared statistic is applicable out of the box since I don't have sample counts, but, again, open to suggestion.

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test seemed to generic and doesn't look like it yields per-$x_j$ statistics.

**EDIT**

Additional clarification: My question is akin to someone supplying a bunch of discrete distributions without any additional context and requesting, "please rank these distributions in order of how non-uniform they are, and tell me which elements of each led you to that conclusion."

Comment: So in your example your "deep neural network" gives you (somehow) $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ (probability measures or laws) such that $\mu_{1}(\{x_{1}\})=0.33$, $\mu_{1}(\{x_{2}\})=0.67$; $\mu_{2}(\{y_{1}\})=\mu_{2}(\{y_{2}\})=0.33$ and $\mu_{2}(\{y_{3}\})=0.34$, where $\{x_{1},x_{2}\}$ and $\{y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}\}$ are the minimal support sets for random variables $X$ and $Y$ having these laws? You do not have any observed sample data, but want to judge what "an extreme" value would be for these two laws?

Comment: Sorry I should have asked: you wish to judge what "an extreme" result would be in terms of observing a certain number of samples in each class (for each law)? - i.e. any single realisation can only be in one of the classes, so what is extreme or not pertains to a sample

Comment: @dandar I might be struggling to be clear since my use case may be unusual (or even ill-posed). $P_i$ don't have known $\mu$, but my "null hypothesis" is that they are all discrete uniform distributions. I'm trying to look through them and find the the values that are most (forgive the abuse of terminology) "non-uniform". I don't have any samples to speak of; each of these $P_i$ is kind of its own sample of size N=1.

Comment: I suppose I could use KL-divergence and look at the terms that contribute most. That would give a per-element measure of non-uniformity.

Comment: I do think any empirical distribution needs reference to samples - i.e. your empirical distributions correspond to some samples somewhere (even if these are imagined). However I am just wondering if you mean to say empirical distribution functions when in fact you mean discrete distributions? You mention both.

Comment: My stats terminology might be off. I'm calling these empirical distributions because they are computed using only data, though in a nonconventional way (through the DNN). And yes, they do correspond to samples somewhere - as a matter of fact, each distribution is generated by passing one data point through the DNN.

I experimented with using the KL-divergence from the discrete uniform distribution for each $P_i$. Qualitatively it seems to yield a good "statistic" / metric in line with what I'm looking for, so I'll continue to experiment with it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**Tenative "answer" addressing notational/terminology issues relating to question**

If anyone has any insights into a "correct" method for comparing "uniformness" that would be welcome, but the idea of distances between functions as proposed by the OP seems sensible.

Let $F_{U}$ be the CDF of a random variable $U$ with discrete uniform distribution with support set $\{a_{1},...,a_{m}\}$, i.e. $m$ support points with $Pr[U=a_{j}]=m^{-1}$ for all $j=1,...,m$, where $Pr[U\leq u]=F_{U}(u)=(\lfloor u\rfloor-a_{1}+1)/(a_{m}-a_{1}+1)$ for $u\in[a_{1},a_{m}]$.

$F_{n}(x)$, the discrete uniform measure, is defined as $F_{n}(x):=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1\{x_{i}\leq x\}$ for some sample $X_{1}=x_{1}$,...$X_{n}=x_{n}$ (regardless of which random variable $X$ say, the sample is a sample of).

Then $F_{n}\equiv F_{U}$ when $n=m$ **and** when the sample contains $n$ unique values since when $\sum_{i}^{n}1\{x_{i}\leq x\}$ increases it will jump by precisely one as $x$ runs through $\mathbb{R}$. Conversely even if $n=m$, if the sample contain just $2$ unique values say, then $F_{n}$ will have just two jumps (at $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$ say) and so $F_{n}\equiv F_{U}$ cannot occur if $m>2$ since $F_{n}(b_{1})=0.5$ and $F_{n}(b_{2})=1$ but $F_{U}(a_{1})=m^{-1}<0.5$. Thus although the sample could be a sample from a continuous random variable, $F_{n}$ will have discrete jumps whose number will not exceed $n$ (and will be equal to $n$ if the sample contains no duplicates).

When you speak of "classes" I think you mean a random variable $X$ having discrete law $\mu_{X}$ with support set $S_{X}=\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}\}$ say. Then $Pr[X=a_{i}]=p_{i}=\mu_{X}(\{a_{i}\})$ for $i=1,2,3$. But the empirical distribution $F_{n}$ of a sample $X_{j}=x_{j}$ for $j=1,2,...,n$ is not the same thing as the distribution function for $X$ unless $x_{j}\in S_{X}$ for all $j$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}1\{x_{j}\leq a_{i}\}=\sum_{a\in S_{X}}1\{a\leq a_{i}\}\mu_{X}(\{a\})$ for all $i=1,2,3$. We can use the notation $F_{X}(a_{i})=\sum_{a\in S_{X}}1\{a\leq a_{i}\}\mu_{X}(\{a\})$ to be notationally similar to the continuous random variable case where the distribution function $F$ is different from the law $\mu$ (i.e. the distribtuion), with the understanding $\mu_{X}(\{x\})=0$ for any $x\not\in S_{X}$.

The terminology is only a distraction here since it seems you know what you want to do - it seems the KL-divergence or something like this is along the right lines. For instance

$$||F_{n}-F_{U}||=\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{sup}|F_{n}(x)-F_{U}(x)|$$

is the uniform distance between $F_{n}$ and $F_{U}$ and

$$||F_{X}-F_{U}||=\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{sup}\left|F_{X}(\{x\})-F_{U}(x)\right|$$

is the uniform distance between $F_{X}$ and $F_{U}$. But remeber $F_{n}$ could have hundreds of jumps and $F_{X}$ only 3 for example - i.e. $F_{n}$ can be very "jumpy". However the concept of distances between functions is I is good thinking.